# Can I pass a file with different paths to Azure DevOps Path include trigger

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have set of azure devops pipelines and I want to use include path triggers for these yaml pipelines. I have multiple pipelines that will have these paths repeated. Is there a way I can pass in a text file with include or exclude paths so I can update in one place rather than each yaml pipeline? Or is there any better way to queue pipelines dynamically based on path changes?